# GWT Geolocation..getCurrentPosition always times out?

Tags: java, html, gwt, geolocation

I am try to get the users gelocation coordinates in a GWT project, but I always end up with a time out error even when the a time-out value of 18000 (3 mins) is used. I don't even get any permission popup from chrome in devmode ?

```
Geolocation geoLoc = Geolocation.getIfSupported();
if(geoLoc != null){
log.info("Geolocation is supported!");
Geolocation.PositionOptions options = new Geolocation.PositionOptions();            
options.setMaximumAge(0);
options.setTimeout(18000);
options.setHighAccuracyEnabled(false);

geoLoc.getCurrentPosition(new Callback<Position, PositionError>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Position result) {  // never called
        Coordinates coords = result.getCoordinates();
        final double lat = coords.getLatitude();
        final double lng = coords.getLongitude();
        log.info("Coordinates: (" + lat + ", " + lng + ")");
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(PositionError error) { // always called
        String message = "";
        switch (error.getCode()) {
          case PositionError.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
            message = "Unknown Error";
            break;
          case PositionError.PERMISSION_DENIED:
            message = "Permission Denied";
            break;
          case PositionError.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
            message = "Position Unavailable";
            break;
          case PositionError.TIMEOUT:
            message = "Time-out";
            break;
          default:
            message = "Unknown error code.";
        }
        log.error("Can't Get Current Position: " + message); // ... Time-out
    }
}, options);
}
```